# How to plot a matrix if there is common data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I am trying to build a 2D matrix using 2 csv files and the matrix should show green colour if both the files have one gene, and red if not present. I made a python code for comparing the 2 files and it will print 1 or 0 in case of presence or absence, respectively. This is that code:

```
import csv
with open('test1.csv','r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    row_str1 = []
    for row in reader:
        row_str1.append(row[1])
print row_str1
with open('test2.csv','r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    row_str2 = []
    for row in reader:
        row_str2.append(row[1])
print row_str2

for const in row_str1:
    for var in row_str2:
        if const == var:
            print "1"
        else:
            print "0"
```

Is there a way for me to present this 1 and 0 in the 2D matrix, it should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZCnm.jpg), but should be green instead of blue and red instead of white.

**EDIT:** This is the code I tried but I am getting green for all the values, and I need to integrate the previous code and this code to get my final script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]])
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green',  'red'])
bounds = [0,  10,  20]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds,  cmap.N)

fig,  ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data,  cmap=cmap,  norm=norm)

ax.grid(which ='major',  axis = 'both',  linestyle = '-',  color = 'k',  linewidth = 2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1));
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1));
plt.show()
```

The result I obtained is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSMU2.png)
I tried to change the boundaries but I was not able to retain all colors together. Is there a way to make this dynamic where it takes the area of all colored boxes?

Please help.
Thank You

Comment: You've done some work on how to figure out which elements from one file are also in the second file. Good work! But you've done nothing about the plotting part. What have you tried? What didn't work? This is not a code writing service, show your work and ask **specific** questions, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am so sorry about this, I had not included the code which I was having issues with, please let me know if any more formating is needed, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indeed change the boundaries to match your data. Also you need to let the Boundary norm match the number of colors you want to have.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
                 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
                 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
                 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]])
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['green',  'red'])
bounds = [0.5,  1.5,  2.5]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds,  len(bounds)-1)

fig,  ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data,  cmap=cmap,  norm=norm)

ax.grid(which ='major',  axis = 'both',  linestyle = '-',  color = 'k',  linewidth = 2)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1));
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 10, 1));
fig.colorbar(im, ticks=[1,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]